# CSRF token is missing error in docker pgadmin

Tags: postgresql, docker, pgadmin

I am trying to create a `docker-compose` stack with `pg` and `pgadmin` as follows,

```
version: '3.1'
services:
  pg-admin:
    image: dpage/pgadmin4
    volumes:
        - /Users/pkaramol/Desktop/backup.tar:/pgadmin4/dvdrental.tar
    ports:
      - "8181:80"
    environment:
      PGADMIN_DEFAULT_EMAIL: user@domain.com
      PGADMIN_DEFAULT_PASSWORD: 1234
    depends_on:
    - pg
  pg:
    image: postgres:12
    volumes:
      - ./pg-data:/var/lib/postgresql/data
    environment:
      POSTGRES_DB: postgres
      POSTGRES_USER: postgres
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: postgres
    restart: always
```

but `pgadmin` logs error out as follows:

```
pg-admin_1  | Traceback (most recent call last):
pg-admin_1  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1811, in full_dispatch_request
pg-admin_1  |     rv = self.preprocess_request()
pg-admin_1  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 2087, in preprocess_request
pg-admin_1  |     rv = func()
pg-admin_1  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/flask_wtf/csrf.py", line 224, in csrf_protect
pg-admin_1  |     self.protect()
pg-admin_1  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/flask_wtf/csrf.py", line 259, in protect
pg-admin_1  |     self._error_response(e.args[0])
pg-admin_1  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/flask_wtf/csrf.py", line 302, in _error_response
pg-admin_1  |     raise CSRFError(reason)
pg-admin_1  | flask_wtf.csrf.CSRFError: 400 Bad Request: The CSRF session token is missing.
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 61, accepted):

Make sure that you close tab that were connected to pgAdmin before start the container.

Comment: Yes, this did it for me. I had a chrome tab open from a previous session. In the mean time I recreated my pgadmin instance so I guess the tokes had changed.

Comment: this works very good.

Comment: Just closing the tab, or even closing chrome didn't work for me, but refreshing without cache (ctrl+shift+r) did

Comment: This does not work for me. I have tried clearing cache, incognito mode, restarting container, using several different browsers. I always get the csrf error

Answer (score 9):

I stumbled upon this in Azure Conatiner Apps and Container Instances. Whenever PGAdmin sits behind a load balancer or Gateway the thing that worked for me was to simply disable the Enhanced Cookie protection flag in as an .env variable.

```
PGADMIN_CONFIG_ENHANCED_COOKIE_PROTECTION="False"
```

Hope this helps someone.

Comment: Thank you! I'm using pgadmin routed through an Azure Application Gateway and this setting allowed the app to work.

Answer (score 6):

Tried the suggestions above but had no luck. In the end what worked for me was setting these two:

```
PGADMIN_CONFIG_WTF_CSRF_CHECK_DEFAULT: 'False'
PGADMIN_CONFIG_WTF_CSRF_ENABLED: 'False'
```

our setup is:

pgadmin 4:7.5 (docker image)

running in Kubernetes

ingress-nginx

AWS ELB

Comment: Those two pgadmin config vars works for me with Docker v4.23.0 on Apple M1 Max and macOS 13.6

Answer (score 4):

Maybe you are running multiple instances of pgAdmin on the same host? At least for us this was the problem. Shutting down one of them resolved the issue.

Answer (score 1):

For me there were three issues. I'm not sure which one solved it:

- Disabled cloudflare cache and then purged the cache
- I am using a non-standard port, 8082 instead of 5050
- I removed the environment variable `PGADMIN_LISTEN_PORT: 8082`

Note I am still using port 8082 and can successfully log in.

Answer (score 1):

For me only clearing cookies solved the problem.

**Update:** clearing the cookies only helps for a short time.

Upgrading pgadmin v4.25 to v6.15 had no effect - same CSRF token missing issue.

The root cause is in Ngninx proxy cookie handling (my pgadmin docker is behind nginx proxy), or rather not handling :)

I moved the pgadmin app from nginx to AWS ALB and that worked around the issue.

I added this config line to nginx server block

```
proxy_pass_header    Set-Cookie;
```

and that seems to fix the issue as well.

Answer (score 0):

I can ran it from `http://127.0.0.1:8701` but when I use custom domain behind NPM I get that error. Well it turned out I was using tag 4.18 so maybe need to try latest :)